# A man that greets a car(?) and pig aliens

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'd like to know the title of a movie that I watched around eight years ago. This movie is in English. I don't remember much about this movie.

Some of the plot/scenes that I remember:

A man greets a car in the beginning and then someone saves him from being hit. There's a house being destroyed at some point. There's also pig-like alien. I remember there's a robot that sounds like Snape from Harry Potter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's one of my favourite.

**[The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371724/)**

Here's a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=the%20hitchhiker%27s%20guide%20to%20the%20galaxy%202005%20):

Comment: The movie was good.  The TV series was better.  The books were excellent.  The radio show was superb.

Comment: The robot sounds like Snape because both were played by Alan Rickman. 

Comment: @SaraM, the robot was voiced by Alan Rickman but played by Warwick Davis.

Comment: I think, more Adams trailer is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyzN7R9t4uI

Comment: @Kruga You would need Snape to fit Alan Rickman inside Marvin. Or CGI...

Comment: So the body of Flitwick, and the voice of Snape. That's a powerful robot wizard right there!